# yum list showing wrong version

Tags: centos, yum, sqlite

I am trying to install freeswitch and while configuring it, it spits out the message.

"checking for sqlite3 >= 3.6.20... Package sqlite3 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sqlite3.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'sqlite3' found"

I have installed sqlite 3.6.20 from the rpm

## yum list shows correct version

# yum list sqlite

Installed Packages

sqlite.i386                                                                    3.6.20-1.el5

## yum install shows wrong version

# yum install sqlite

Package matching sqlite-3.3.6-7.i386 already installed. Checking for update.

Nothing to do

I am using centos 2.6.18-238.el5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct version installed, but the `configure` command is looking for the `-devel` package. Do a `yum install sqlite3-devel`, which is what gives you the header files and the `pkg-config` file `sqlite3.pc`, and you should be okay.

Comment: thank you it worked. yum --enablerepo=atrpms-testing install sqlite*
from [here](http://pkgs.org/centos-5/atrpms-testing-i386/sqlite-3.6.20-1.el5.i386.rpm.html)